# SAS - How to get the column name as a value to another column (based on its value as condition)

Tags: sas

Three columns are depicted in the picture - abc, def, and xyz. The next two columns are dervied from these 3 columns. **min** column calculates the min value out of these 3 columns. **mincol** column should give the column name which belongs to the **min** value.
[image: sample]

Comment: Please don't post your data as images. In order to answer your question someone needs to now type it out and then code an answer to your question. You'll get faster responses if you post it as text and show what you've tried as well. Please review the posting guidelines here [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- Use the `VNAME` function to retrieve the variable name of an element in a variable array.
- Use the `WHICHN` function to find the index of the first occurring value in an array
- Use the `MIN` function to find the minimum value in an array

Put them all together, such as:

```
data have;
  input abc def xzy;
  length min 8 mincol $32;
  datalines;
 1 2  3
 2 0  3
-1 0 -3
;

data want;
  set have;
  array values abc def xzy;
  min = min(of values(*));
  mincol = vname(values(whichn(min,of values(*))));
run;
```

[image]